# Linaro version vs GCC version

Tags: gcc, gnu, linaro

I have just noticed that Linaro version and GCC version do not match.

As of today current stable version of GCC is [6.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/).

Current stable version of Linaro is [6.1-2016.08](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/arm-eabi/) (link from Linaro's main page).

There is also Linaro version [6.2-2016.11](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/) available for download.

Release notes for [Linaro 6.1-2016.08](http://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/6.1-2016.08/) and [Linaro 6.2-2016.11](http://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/6.2-2016.11/) contain information about GCC 6 with the [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html) to its release notes.

Based on it I expected that Linaro 6.1-2016.08 and Linaro 6.2-2016.11 are based on GCC 6.1 and GCC 6.2 respectively.

But it turned out that actual version of GCC in Linaro builds is 5.3:

```
yurko@my_pc /cygdrive/f/Linaro/gcc-linaro-6.1.1-2016.08-i686-mingw32_arm-eabi/bin
$ arm-eabi-gcc.exe -E -dM - < /dev/null | grep __GNUC__
#define __GNUC__ 5

yurko@my_pc /cygdrive/f/Linaro/gcc-linaro-6.1.1-2016.08-i686-mingw32_arm-eabi/bin
$ arm-eabi-gcc.exe --version
arm-eabi-gcc.exe (GCC) 5.3.0


yurko@my_pc /cygdrive/f/Linaro/gcc-linaro-6.2.1-2016.11-i686-mingw32_arm-eabi/bin
$ arm-eabi-gcc.exe -E -dM - < /dev/null | grep __GNUC__
#define __GNUC__ 5

yurko@my_pc /cygdrive/f/Linaro/gcc-linaro-6.2.1-2016.11-i686-mingw32_arm-eabi/bin
$ arm-eabi-gcc.exe --version
arm-eabi-gcc.exe (GCC) 5.3.0
```

[Linaro GCC FAQ Page](https://wiki.linaro.org/WorkingGroups/ToolChain/FAQ) says nothing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The question is not relevant.

It turned out that *arm-eabi-gcc.exe* from wrong toolchain was used.

I should have specified explicitly the path by preceding it with './'.